# Office web addin - GetFileAsync is not giving proper data

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am working in Office word web addin. In this, i am using `Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize:10000 }` to get whole document content.

Once we got all byte array from slices then converting to string, system always converting as like as follows (whatever content is there in document)

[image]

Please let me know, how to overcome this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Please don't use screenshots of code. Instead, paste and format the code itself in your question. Screenshots are remarkably hard to read/parse and can't be copied and pasted for easily replicating the issue.